# Protractor tests working on one machine but not another machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have a suite of Protractor/Jasmine E2E Automated tests that work flawlessly on my personal computer.  I was trying to have someone else check out the tests and run them locally on their own computer.  Even after what seems to be an identical environment set up, their tests don't find or click the correct elements and end up failing immediately.

Has anyone ran into this or have any insight on trouble shooting?

I'm running Protractor version 5.0.0 and webdriver version 11.1.1

Comment: Fail reason, exceptions etc would help I think....

Comment: It's a common can't find element to click exception.  I don't have access to his logs at the moment but it's nothing out of the ordinary.  I've checked and triple checked and quadruple checked that all the elements are the same, the environments and version are the same, and the browsers are the same.

Comment: you said "tests don't find or click" so there are different exceptions, still you should provide logs. I think what more can be different on his environment... maybe screen size? You should also add screenshots on fail, it can help to find fail reasons

Comment: Right agreed, I just don't have access to it at the moment.  It's a "Cannot click on element: ElementNotVisibleError".  Screen size is a good thought, that gave me troubles before I'll have to double check on that.

Comment: I edited my comment, not sure if you seen it... But screenshots (when fail) will help you a lot in debugging

Comment: I do have screenshots set.  And I can visually see what's happening as well.  Stack trace doesn't provide anything and screenshot is just sitting on the page.  Size and protected mode settings were not the issue so far.

Comment: It could be timing issues. If your machine is a little faster or if the other machine has more stuff running in the background, etc. the test may run slower and start hitting issues. Add some explicit waits in problem areas, e.g. wait for element to be visible or clickable, etc.

Comment: Also possible is network issue, and timing problems mentioned by @JeffC. For example your friends machine has bad internet connection, and tested application working very slow

Comment: @kotoj if we were in the same room on the same network would networking still be viable? and if the tested application is running differently then would the "wait for element to be clickable/visible" solution also solve this?

Comment: @d.rodriguez I use ethernet cable, my colleague use wifi so it is possible to have different network in 1 room, but I've not said this is sure reason, just wondering. If you have "Cannot click on element" error, then yes, "wait for element clickable" may help if it is performance issue (machine/test/application/network issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can search for differences in versions of protractor, webdriver, libs, etc and eventually find but it won't give you a solution. The solution is the container like docker. You don't give your friend the tests so he has to get up and running the same environment, you give him the environment instead. All he has to do is just run the docker and tell you the results.